# Is Pug context free?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, pug

I was thinking to make a Pug parser but besides the indents are well-known to be context-sensitive (that can be trivially hacked with a lexer feedback loop to make it almost context-free which is adopted by Python), what otherwise makes it not context-free?

XML tags are definitely not context-free, that each starting tag needs to match an end tag, but Pug does not have such restriction, that makes me wonder if we could just parse each starting identifier as a production for a tag root.

Comment: See my Quora answer on how parsers have to work, regardless of whether language is context-free or not: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-parse-a-language-having-a-non-CFG-grammar-with-flex-and-bison/answer/Ira-Baxter

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that Pug seems to be missing, at least from a casual scan of its website, is a formal description of its syntax. Or even an informal description. Perhaps I wasn't looking in right places.

Still, based on the examples, it doesn't look awful. There will be some challenges; in particular, it does not have a uniform tokenisation context, so the scanner is going to be complicated, not just because of the indentation issue. (I got the impression from the section on whitespace that the indentation rule is much stricter than Python's, but I didn't find a specification of what it is exactly. It appeared to me that leading whitespace after the two-character indent is significant whitespace. But that doesn't complicate things much; it might even simplify the task.)

What will prove interesting is handling embedded JavaScript. You will at least need to tokenise the embedded JS, and the corner cases in the JS spec make it non-trivial to tokenise without parsing. Anyway, just tokenising isn't sufficient to know where the embedded code terminates. (For the lexical challenge, consider the correct identification of regular expression literals. `/=` might be the start of a regex or it might be a divide-and-assign operator; how a subsequent `{` is tokenised will depend on that decision.) Template strings present another challenge (recursive embedding). However, JavaScript parsers do exist, so you might be able to leverage one.

---

In other words, recognising tag nesting is not going to be the most challenging part of your project. Once you've identified that a given token is a tag, the nesting part is trivial (and context-free) because it is precisely defined by the indentation, so a DEDENT token will terminate the tag.

However, it is worth noting that tag parsing is not particularly challenging for XML (or XML-like HTML variants). If you adopt the XML rule that close tags cannot be omitted (except for self-closing tags), then the tagname in a close tag does not influence the parse of a correct input. (If the tagname in the close tag does not match the close tag in the corresponding open tag, then the input is invalid. But the correspondence between open and close tags doesn't change.) Even if you adopt the HTML-5 rule that close tags cannot be omitted except in the case of a finite list of special-case tagnames, then you could theoretically do the parse with a CFG. (However, the various error recovery rules in HTML-5 are far from context free, so that would only work for input which did not require rematching of close tags.)

Ira Baxter makes precisely this point in the cross-linked post he references in a comment: you can often implement context-sensitive aspects of a language by ignoring them during the parse and detecting them in a subsequent analysis, or even in a semantic predicate during the parse. Correct matching of open- and close tagnames would fall into this category, as would the "declare-before-use" rule in languages where the declaration of an identifier does not influence the parse. (Not true of C or C++, but true in many other languages.)

Even if these aspects cannot be ignored -- as with C `typedef`s, for example -- the simplest solution might be to use an ambiguous CFG and a parsing technology which produces all possible parses. After the parse forest is generated, you could walk the alternatives and reject the ones which are inconsistent. (In the case of C, that would include an alternative parse  in which a name was typedef'd and then used in a context where a typename is not valid.)